# Conditional Binomial Question

Tags: self-study

Lost touch on some basics:

$X \in Bin(n,p)$. Suppose that we know $P(X \ge l)$. Can we get a distribution for $P(X=x | X \ge l)$, $l \le n$?

I would assume we use bayes rule and find $P(X=x, X \ge l$)? Maybe I'm missing something but is there a known for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple conditional probability: $P(A|B) = P(AB)/P(B)$

$P(X=x|X\geq l) = P(X=x\cap X\geq l)/P(X\geq l) $

$\hspace{3.6cm}= P(X=x)/P(X\geq l)\,,\quad x=l,l+1,\ldots,n$

(... and $0$ otherwise, naturally).

You're dealing with a [truncated distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution#Definition).

Note that the denominator is simply a scaling constant that scales up the old probability function up so that it sums to 1 over the new, restricted range for $X$.